# Wait for a readable file descriptor and a writeable one

Tags: linux, select

I need to wait for something to read from file descriptor A and then only read it if file descriptor B is writeable.
My first implementation was like this (Pseudocode):

```
while (true) {
  select(A readable, B writeable, timeout)
  if (A was readable and B was writeable) {
    ReadFromAWriteToB();
  }
}
```

This had the issue that select returned as soon one of the conditions occurred.  This was an issue because A was readable say 10% of the time, but B was writeable say 90% of the time, so it would wake up to write to B even though we usually didn't have any data to read from A.

My next implementation was like this:

```
while (true) {
  select(A readableB, timeout);
  if (A was readable) {
    select(B writeable, 0); // Check if it is writeable right now
    if (B was writeable) {
      ReadFromAWriteToB();
    }
  }
}
```

This was better, but I get peaks where A is readable so the first select returns straight away, but B is not writeable, so I would get into a busy loop until B is writeable again.

So I can add a small wait in the second select, such as 1 millisecond.
What I really want to be able to do is select/poll until both conditions are valid, not just one or the other, but I don't think select/poll support this.
Is there a better API to use or a better way to structure this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a sleep after finding out that B wasn't writable?

```
while (true) {
  select(A readableB, timeout);
  if (A was readable) {
    select(B writeable, 0); // Check if it is writeable right now
    if (B was writeable) {
      ReadFromAWriteToB();
    }
    else {
      sleep for an appropriate amount of time
    }
  }
}
```

This will:

- prevent the tight loop when A is ready and B is not
- makes sure that we always make fresh check of A before checking B

If we can wait for an unlimited amount of time after finding A is ready, we could rewrite the loop like this:

```
while (true) {
  select(A readableB, timeout);
  if (A was readable) {
    b_timeout = 0
    while true {
      select(B writeable, b_timeout); // Check if it is writeable right now
      if (B was writeable) {
        ReadFromAWriteToB();
        break;
      }
      sleep for a small amount of time to prevent tight loop around B
      b_timeout += a few milli seconds
    }
  }
}
```

This will

- prevent the tight loop as in the previous solution
- reduce the number of times we check A after finding it is ready

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can simplify the second example by just selecting with NULL timeout which waits forever.

Comment: Another option is to use a short timeout in the select writeable to avoid the sleep.  I think I'll use this option in my project.  Thanks for working through it with me!